# Dealing with transparent objects, combining two Xtion

Tags: slam, navigation, calibration, xtion, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to make 3D map of my office with XtionPRO Live, the biggest problem i met so far is dealing with transparent/aborbing objects etc. I tried to avoid them but they still reflects (windows, glass doors) and i got random erros on my map (like inclined in the middle of room). Other things like glasses or bottles are hard to avoid. I couldn't find any solution and it's seems to be impossible to solve problem due to Xtion sensor is using IR.
The only thing i found is publication about combining two Xtions ([http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~hema/rgbd-workshop-2014/papers/Alhwarin.pdf](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Ehema/rgbd-workshop-2014/papers/Alhwarin.pdf)). I'm new to RoS/mapping and publication I found is too complex for me to implementation. I understand main assumption but I'm not sure how to prepare it and use with RTAB-map.
I am able to get second Xtion/Kinect but how should i calibrate them? Earlier i used (http://wiki.ros.org/action/show/openni_launch/Tutorials/IntrinsicCalibration) but in that way i can pass mono calibration for sensors separately, how can i combine them? Is there any way to achieve goal with available packages? Is there any other solutions to deal with objects like that in RTAB-map?

Thanks for answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240287/dealing-with-transparent-objects,-combining-two-xtion./) by [necro](https://answers.ros.org/users/27527/necro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-07-25**:
I don't to which extent you can integrate it in RTAB map but sonars are the solution to transparent objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reflective and transparent surfaces are very challenging for mapping approaches. For the two Xtions approach you refer, it is a stereo setup with IR images. You may use [stereo calibration tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration) to calibrate the Xions with each other. Well, you may have to hide the IR pattern when calibrating. On runtime, you may use [stereo_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc) to generate the disparity image. Be aware that this package may assume horizontal stereo, so you may have to rotate the images/camera_info, then rotate back the output disparity. By converting the disparity to depth ([rtabmap_ros/disparity_to_depth](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap_ros.2BAC8-disparity_to_depth)) and left IR image to Gray scale, you could use rgb-d interface of rtabmap.

However, some surfaces are just very difficult to detect with vision/laser, just think about a mirror or clean glass...

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [necro](https://answers.ros.org/users/27527/necro/) on 2016-07-26**:
Thanks for Your involvement! Already I'm waiting for second Xtion and in meantime I got ZED camera to play with. [ZED Wrapper](http://tinyurl.com/hho66hs) got this file, so why i need to run [rosrun tf static_transform_publisher](http://tinyurl.com/z9cdr4w)? Seems very similar for me what's the diff

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-07-26**:
Oh, that [commit](http://tinyurl.com/ht968ex) (June 21) modified the TF frames of the ZED. They are also starting their own odometry with the camera driver. The tutorial should be updated.

**Comment by [necro](https://answers.ros.org/users/27527/necro/) on 2016-07-26**:
So what should i do? Without line from Your tutorial i got:

```
odometry: Could not get transform from camera_link to /zed_tracked_frame (stamp=1469541052.943110) after 0.200000 seconds ("wait_for_transform_duration"=0.200000)!
```

After running your line i can successfully see rtabmap gui.

**Comment by [necro](https://answers.ros.org/users/27527/necro/) on 2016-07-26**:
Other thing is that my clouds are "waved". My ZED is uncalibrated in ROS but i read that it's pre-calibrated and I don't need to do anything. Here is my screenshot:
[http://i.imgur.com/Q6Fz9on.png](https://i.imgur.com/Q6Fz9on.png) 
The wall on right isn't straight. Does that camera need more clouds to give depth?

**Comment by [necro](https://answers.ros.org/users/27527/necro/) on 2016-07-27**:
Using ZED Depth Viewer with this tool I could obtain pointclouds straight from the camera and it's waved too. Other thing is that I can see only one cloud, because tool ZEDfu for mapping is still unreleased for Linux. I will try to check it under Windows and see if assembling will straighten image.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-07-27**:
You may set a maximum cloud depth to filter far waved clouds. See also "To have similar results than ZedFu..." section in https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/releases/0.11.7.